# Can't get SplashScreen-Image and classpath to work at the same time

Tags: java, splash-screen

I have the following structure:

```
myapp.jar
lib/
```

`myapp.jar` is an executable jar that includes a splash screen image resource and uses the `SplashScreen-Image` manifest entry.  `lib/` contains a bunch of other jar files.

If I run `java -jar myapp.jar`, the splash screen is displayed but (as expected) the program can't find its dependencies in `lib/`.

If I run `java -cp myapp.jar:lib/* mypackage.MainClass`, it finds its dependencies but the splash screen is not shown.  `SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()` returns null.

If I run `java -cp myapp.jar:lib/* -splash:images/splash.jpg mypackage.MainClass`, the splash screen still doesn't work.  Apparently it's treating `images/splash.jpg` as a relative filesystem path, not a classpath resource.

Trying to combine `-cp` with `-jar`, i.e., `java -cp myapp.jar:lib/* -jar myapp.jar` behaves exactly like `java -jar myapp.jar`.  `-cp` is apparently ignored with `-jar`.

Is there any solution besides supplying the splash image separately from the executable jar?

Comment: I’m afraid there is no other way.  The [SplashScreen documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) doesn’t explicitly mention the `-jar` option (though I read it as implied), but it makes it clear that there are only two ways to initialize the splash image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Class-Path` entry to your jar manifest, so you can use the `-jar` option while still finding your dependencies.