# Not show splash screen declare in MANIFEST

Tags: java, gradle, splash-screen

java 1.8

Gradle

I crate my app distributive by

./gradle distZip

As result in my application jar has the next MANIFEST

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.png
```

In jar in folder `/images/splash.png` EXIST image file.

But when I start my app the splash screen is not show.

Gradle create `myProj.bat` with the next content:

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-splash:C:\dev\temp\myProj\app/src/main/resources/images/splash.png"
```

Client run app by "myProj.bat".

And it's not work on production. It's work ONLY in development environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397247/cant-get-splashscreen-image-and-classpath-to-work-at-the-same-time

Comment: There is a tutorial on splash screens: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: @akarnokd Not help. I use gradle to create distributive

Comment: How do you run your program? You have to run it with `java -jar thejarfile.jar` for it to show the splash screen. For that, you need `Main-Class` declared in the manifest too.

Comment: @akarnokd I was update my post

Comment: Did you deploy the bat and the image to production? Did you point that path of `-splash:` to it?

Comment: @akarnokd How point to image INSIDE jar?

Comment: Splash image inside jar works only with `-jar` launch. `-splash` only works from images in the file system.